# Are the local files using the local PHP if these files are sync with files in a Virtual Machine?

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine

Noob here seeking enlightenment. I understand that there are files that are in-sync with one another, one located in the `VM`(e.g. `Laravel-Homestead`) and the other inside the`local` machine. And if I provisioned `PHP` in my `VM` then my `VM` will use that `PHP`.

What about the files, located within local machine, does it use the local `PHP` (if installed)? If so, two `PHP`s are working on two different locations? Or do they(local files) execute at all? Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a virtual machine typically requires two components: a **host** and a **guest**.

The **host** (local) operating system you are running on your computer (whatever you're using Windows, Mac OS X, etc) and the **guest** Ubuntu Linux running within your Laravel Homestead VM, are two independent systems.

> **Your Laravel application runs solely withing the VM.**

So the software required to run your app (nginx, PHP, MySQL, etc.) only needs to be installed within the VM operating system.

The only purpose of having files synced between your host and guest operating systems, is to allow you to make changes to your files locally, and have them immediately be available within the VM enviroment. Nothing is run on your local OS.

Comment: Finally a person with a kind heart. Thanks a million Bogdan! There's a lot of  arrogant SOBs in this community. I post a question expecting an answer, I get a negative rating on my question instead. Really helpful people. I dont think I'm coming back to this site. Anyway, thanks again Bogdan.

Comment: You question might appear as slightly unclear at first (perhaps because of the way you worded you statements). As with many communities, there are those who have a "itchy trigger finger", in this case when it comes to downvoting. That would be very much ok, if they could be bothered to leave a comment letting you know the reason they downvoted, so you could fix the question. Don't let one negative experience drive you away. I would suggest reading the [Asking Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), to make sure you write questions that would not give anyone reason to downvote.